# Exclude last line from StreamReader in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, int, streamreader

I'm saving some DataGridView's data into a text file(for data I'm refering to the content of each cell), and at the last line of the TXT File, I am storing the number of rows of the dataGridView with a "-" at the start of the line.

Now, I can read my data perfectly into my DVG, but how can I exclude the last line which contains my row count and also use it to read its stored int?

The code I use for reading the data into the DVG:

```
void LoadDVGData()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(open.FileName);
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in editDGV.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                string content = sr.ReadLine();
                cell.Value = content;
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
```

Thanks in Advance. - CCB

Comment: What do you have so far to solve this problem?

Comment: Sincerely, I don't know how to start.

Comment: You said you can read your data into the DGV - excluding the last line is just one extra step. Can you show your code for loading the data?

Comment: Ok, I'll update the question with the dataRead code.

Comment: What if your file runs out of lines before you go through all your `editDGV.Rows.Cells`?

Comment: How about calling `File.ReadAllLines` and then looping `for (int i=0;i<lines.Count-2;i++)`?

Comment: @vesan That works for small files. Considering it's a DGV, it may work fine.

Comment: I think it would make your life much easier if the count was the _first_ line of the file, not last.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to maintain one token of look ahead so that you can answer the question, "Is this the last line?" (if you have a current line, but no next line, you're positioned at the last line.

Here's one approach, which is probably about as simple as it gets:

```
void LoadDVGData()
{
  using ( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(open.FileName) )
  {
    string currentLine = sr.ReadLine() ;
    string nextLine    = sr.ReadLine() ;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in editDGV.Rows)
    {
      foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
      {
        if ( currentLine == null ) throw new InvalidOperationException("Hmph. We seem to have run out of input data");

        cell.Value = currentLine ;

        currentLine = nextLine ;
        nextLine = sr.ReadLine() ;

      } //end cols loop
    } // end rows loop

  } // end using block

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume `sr` is the `StreamReader` that reads your text file - you should wrap that in a `using` or `try..finally` block to ensure correct cleanup in case of errors.

Your current setup doesn't work very well for cases where the text file doesn't match the number of rows / cells that you have in the `DataGridView` (DGV): you try reading a value from the file for each cell and if the wrong file is specified, you may attempt to read beyond the end of the file. You should have more error handling around this code because there may be various problem spots during reading the file: too few rows, too few cells for a row, invalid value for a particular cell, etc.

Your setup doesn't lend itself very well to handling. If you control the format of the text file, I'd recommend to change the format so that the very first row is the count and then each row in the text file describes a complete row for the DGV, using `TAB` as the delimiter. It'd be far simpler to load such a file. (You can even have the row count and column count on the first row to give you even more information about the data; you can never have too much metadata about input data.)

So your new textfile format would look something like:

```
3{TAB}5
R1C1{TAB}R1C2{TAB}R1C3{TAB}R1C4{TAB}R1C5{CRLF}
R2C1{TAB}R2C2{TAB}R2C3{TAB}R2C4{TAB}R2C5{CRLF}
R3C1{TAB}R3C2{TAB}R3C3{TAB}R3C4{TAB}R3C5{CRLF}
```

If you cannot change the text file format, then just read the file twice - first seek to the end of the file and read back to the end of the line before the last - then just read one line from it - it should be the row count. You can do this by looking for a newline in the file going from the end. Then just seek to the beginning of the file and read so many lines from it.

**Edit:**

As @vesan commented under the question, if your input file is not huge, you can just call `File.ReadAllLines()` to get all lines in a `string[]`. It's trivial to process it then. Using a more convenient file format would work, though, for any file size. Reading all lines assumes that the input file is not huge.

**Edit 2:**

For example (error handling omitted for brevity):

```
var sLines = File.ReadAllLines ( open.FileName );
var nRowCount = int.Parse ( sLines[sLines.Length - 1] );
var nIndex = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in editDGV.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        cell.Value = sLines[nIndex];
        nIndex++;
    }
}
```

If your text file is correct, `nRowCount` will have the correct number of rows and you'll never actually read the last element of your array into the DGV.

Comment: Yeah, I know that if I select the wrong file, my DVG will be messed up, I just used a .txt for test, but I will change the format later, maybe to a custom one. If I would read the file twice, how can I ignore the last line when reading it into the DVG??

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss If you change the file format, you'd have the row / column count on the _first_ line - you simple read one line and all the rest of the lines are data. Your problem is much simpler then. Actually, if you can freely change the file format, I'd just go for either XML (it's human editable but has structure) or full binary (not human editable but very easy to read / write and detect errors). If you control the input file format, just choose a format that has all the data and is convenient to handle - you can pick any layout you like.

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss Sorry, I misread your comment - if you read the file twice (not changing the format), then you first read the last line - this gives you the row count. After that you read so many rows from the file - if the file is correct, you should finish reading before ever reaching the last line on the 2nd pass.

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss If you _can_ change the file format, do it as early as possible - no point in implementing some complicated logic to read the data when you can do it just once and more easily.

Comment: Yes, it is a small file, just like 10 or 20 lines of data.

Comment: @ChrisCreateBoss If that's _guaranteed_ to be the case, just use `File.ReadAllText()` and grab the last array element as the number of rows.